# Tkinter OptionMenu command Exception

Tags: python, exception, tkinter, optionmenu

I want to create a tkinter `OptionMenu` that edits another `OptionMenu` when it's changed. So I tried to create a `command=` argument which makes a specific command run on every update of the `OptionMenu`, like it does when I use the `command=` argument to a button, spinbox etc.

```
tl.wktype = OptionMenu(tl,wktypevar, *wk_types,command=typeupdate)
```

Somewhere else in the code is the `typeupdate()` Command - for debug purposes right now.

```
def typeupdate():
    typeval = tl.wktype.get()
    print(typeval)
```

The exception python throws is the following:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3300, in __call__
    self.__callback(self.__value, *args)
TypeError: typeupdate() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

What positional arguments does `typeupdate()` think is given and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is given the value that is clicked.  To demonstrate, consider this script:

```
from tkinter import Tk, OptionMenu, StringVar
root = Tk()
def func(val):
    print(val)
var = StringVar()
OptionMenu(root, var, "one", command=func).grid()
root.mainloop()
```

When run (and when I click on the option "one" in the optionmenu), it prints "one" in the terminal.

So, in summary, add `val` (or any other argument name) to your function declaration and it will work:

```
def typeupdate(val):
```

Comment: You again? Thank you very much :D

Comment: @CrushedPixel - Not a problem at all.  Also, as my profile says, I specialize in Tkinter.  Thus, questions on that topic are are some of my favorites. ;)

Comment: Just one question left - how can I combine this with a lambda:command() to pass more than just the value? For example I need a variable called "tl" to be passed, too, but if I do it the "normal" lambda way (command=lambda:cmdname(var,tl)) it throws a similar exception.

Comment: Give an argument to the `lambda`:  `command=lambda val:cmdname(var,tl)`.  `lambda` can accept arguments and keyword arguments just like a function (since, technically, it _is_ a function).

Comment: If I do it like this, it throws another exception: def typeupdate(tl): `if val == globals.wk_types[0]:
  tl.wkname = OptionMenu(tl,wknamevar, *wkt1_list,command=typeupdate)` `command=lambda val:typeupdate(tl)` throws the exception: `NameError: global name 'val' is not defined`

Comment: It's hard to see exactly what is the problem from the comment, but I think that is because, in `typeupdate`, you named the argument `tl`.  Thus, inside the function's scope, `val` isn't defined.  Rename `tl` to `val` or vise versa.